# How to return the tty of the frontmost/raised/focused Terminal window?

Tags: applescript

How can I get the `tty` of the frontmost (or raised, or focused) Terminal window? (This is needed so that I can determine whether a script is running in the foreground or background.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script returns the `tty` of the frontmost Terminal window, or the empty string if all such windows are minimised/hidden:

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript

tell application "Terminal"
  if frontmost is true
    repeat with w in windows
      if (frontmost of w) is true then
        set t to (selected tab of w)
        return (tty of t) as string
      end if
    end repeat
  end if
end tell
```

Usage:

```
$ frontmost-tty
/dev/ttys001
$ tty
/dev/ttys001
$ sleep 5 ; frontmost-tty # switch Terminals
/dev/ttys000
```

Comment: As a script: https://github.com/ithinkihaveacat/dotfiles/blob/master/fish/functions/terminal-frontmost.fish